# Oracle stored procedure error

Tags: oracle10g

Im a newbie to Oracle and trying to create a new procedure but getting a error,

Error-expression P_EMP_SAL cannot be used as an INTO target of SELECT/FETCH statement..

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE getempsal(
        p_emp_id IN NUMBER,
        p_emp_month IN CHAR,
        p_emp_sal in INTEGER)

AS
BEGIN
    SELECT EMP_SAL
    INTO p_emp_sal
    FROM EMPLOYEE_SAL
    WHERE EMP_ID = p_emp_id
    and EMP_MONTH = p_emp_month;

END getempsal;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You specify `IN` for a parameter you want to return from a procedure. Try `p_emp_sal OUT INTEGER`.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/subprograms.htm#i4107

Comment: it worked but how do I call it?..I tried calling using getempsal(1,'JAN',OUTVAR) but get a error

Comment: @user1050619 it depends of the environment you use for calling. can you be a bit more specific and provide a sample with error?

Comment: Im calling it in oracle toad. getempsal(1,'JAN',OUTVAR) given me invalid statement

Comment: try `declare var integer; begin getempsal(1, 'JAN', var); end;`?

Answer (score -1):

Take out put parameter refcursor 
and make changes in body of procedure

```
Open outCursor for SELECT EMP_SAL
    INTO p_emp_sal
    FROM EMPLOYEE_SAL
    WHERE EMP_ID = p_emp_id
    and EMP_MONTH = p_emp_month;
```

Comment: if you want single value you can take varialble instead of cursor